# Check if the past candles are the same type in PineScript

Tags: pine-script, candlestick-chart

I am trying to check if the past `n` candles are of the same type.

For example, are all five previous candles bullish, or are they all bearish.

With my approach, I keep getting an error:

```
lines 30:37: Return type of one of the 'if' blocks is not compatible with return type of other block(s) (void; series[bool]; series[bool])
```

What am I getting wrong in my iteration?

Thank you all in advance.

I am also willing to try out any other working approach/ ideas.

```
// Determine if we have a valid setup
isBullish = true
isBearish = true

for i = (iterationCount - 1) to 0
    notSeries = not(isBullish or isBearish)

    if notSeries
        break
    else if close[i] > open[i] and isBullish
        isBearish := false
    else 
        isBullish := false
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why it throws that error, because even if you put `isBearish := false` before the `break`, the error persists, even though every path in the `if` statement returns a `bool`.

I'd write it like this, because you don't need the `break` for the evaluation of your `isBullish` and `isBearish`. You only need the `break` to stop your `for` loop.

```
for i = (iterationCount - 1) to 0
    notSeries = not(isBullish or isBearish)

    if notSeries
        break

    if close[i] > open[i] and isBullish
        isBearish := false
    else 
        isBullish := false
```